# Winform Control.Refresh - guaranteed synchronous?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Invoking the WinForms [Control.Refresh](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.refresh.aspx) method is described in MSDN as:

*Forces the control to invalidate its client area and immediately redraw itself and any child controls.*

I am debugging an intermittent issue that seems to occur when the attached display is switching scanout signals (effectively changing resolution), in which a Control.Refresh appears to not be generating the expected Control.OnPaint call.  I am instrumenting the application to get more information, however I'm curious if this could actually be the runtime deciding not to invoke the OnPaint because it detects the display is momentarily blanked out.

This seems unlikely to me, and I expect I'll find some other smoking gun, but I'm posting on the off-chance somebody else has seen this in the wild, and has some recommendations for handling this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not guaranteed.  If the control does not have a screen to draw on, it won't fire the paint message.

But once the control is on the screen again, the paint message should fire again.

Are you trying to paint debug information?  If the control isn't on the screen, what are you expecting to happen when you call refresh?

Comment: Thanks - I've devised a couple of experiments to try and validate this, but they've given me contradictory results.  I made a simple form, in which OnMove writes to console, and fires a Refresh.  As you describe, while the form is on the screen I see the Refresh (and ensuing OnPaint) fire.  If I move it offscreen (using the upper-left move and arrow keys) - the Refresh stops firing until some portion of the form is on-screen again.  However, if I create a Timer and have it change the Location of the Form such that it scrolls off to the left of my screen, I *do* receive OnMove/OnPaint events.

Comment: @holtavolt I just tried it to make sure, but a timer doesn't do anything different with the paint event if the control is offscreen.  OnMove, sure, but not Paint.

Comment: Do you have your OnMove performing a Refresh()?  I do, which causes the OnPaint to fire, even if the control is offscreen.

Comment: @holtavolt Yes I do and it doesn't fire OnPaint.  Whatever it is you are trying to do, you probably shouldn't be putting logic in the paint event.

Comment: What are we doing differently?  This is always firing the OnPaint: http://pastebin.com/Jc6hnVef  - I agree on the paint event logic.

Comment: @holtavolt For your testing purposes, I don't think you should be moving the form "back" to the screen.  Here are my changes: [pastebin.com/qkw9gcvH](http://pastebin.com/qkw9gcvH).

Comment: Root cause turned out to be a deeper framework issue with our command pattern implementation.  Your initial answer that the paint is not guaranteed is correct, marking as such.